# Insertion Sort output is not as expected

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, break, insertion-sort

My insertion sort output is not correct. When i tried to call insertionSort method, returned array is not sorted

is it correct use of break statement?

```
public int[] insertionSort(int [] arr){
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=i-1;){
            int temp;
            if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
                temp=arr[i]; arr[i]=arr[j]; arr[j]=temp; 
                break;
            }
            else j++;
            }
        }
        return arr;
}
```

called method with `int [] array = {10,5,6,7,1,9,3,8}`, but result is incorrect:

> Output After Sorting: 1, 3, 7, 8, 5, 10, 6, 9,  // output is not sorted but it changed by somewhat

Comment: Please try to search a correct java implementation of insertion sort and compare with yours to find out the problem

Comment: Why are you breaking within the if statement?

Comment: what happened inside if, can you explain?

Comment: You are breaking inside the inner loop, therefore exiting it. Look at the pseudocode on Wikipedia. Nothing there breaks from a loop.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works:

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            while (j > 0 && arr[j] < arr[j - 1]) {
                // Swap
                int tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = tmp;

                j--;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

One of the problems with your code is that you will put `i-th` element at the correct position, but possibly mess up the position of the element that was already at the right position.

The idea of the insertion sort is to insert `i-th` element at the correct position, which implies that you have to move all elements to the right. However, in your case you just swap `j-th` element and `i-th` after finding the correct position.

The example:
`1 3 5 8 10` this is the current state of the array
Now you try to insert element `6` and you find that the correct position is `3`, so you swap them and the result is:
`1 3 5 6 10 8` which messed up the position for number `8`.

Comment: Thanks for your support,